# Rails Server Not Starting In OSX 10.73

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, webrick

Installed Rails 3.2.3 and MySQL 5.6 fine on my OSX 10.7.3

I created a new project called "simple_cms" and then, in the terminal, tried to launch webrick with "rails server" and got nothing.

Hideyoshis-MacBook-Pro:simple_CMS gregpfeffer$ rails s
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /Users/gregpfeffer/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
    from script/rails:6:in`require'
    from script/rails:6
Hideyoshis-MacBook-Pro:simple_CMS gregpfeffer$ sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
install_name_tool: can't open file: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle (No such file or directory)

Comment: are you sure that mysql is running on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

try adding:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

To your .bash_profile

this assumes you accepted the default installation location for mysql